# Select documents that are not tagged

Tags: mysql, join

Assuming my database has 3 tables:

```
Documents
Tags
Documents_Tags (the join table)
```

I know how to find the tags assigned to a document using a LEFT JOIN, but I'm having trouble finding the tags that are not assigned.

```
SELECT * FROM `documents_tags`
    LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `documents_tags`.`tag_id`
    WHERE `document_id` = 111;
```

I've tried different joins, but I keep getting only one record. I thought there was a way to join all the tags and then limit the results to where the document is null?

**EDIT**: In the above example I need to find all tags not assigned to document `111`.

Comment: But in the above query, you are trying to find all tags **actually assigned** to 111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Tags.name -- or whatever it is
FROM
    tags
    LEFT JOIN documents_tags dt ON (tags.id = dt.tag_id AND dt.document_id = 111)
WHERE dt.id IS NULL
```